# Given a vertex v1, how can I get the vertex v2 whose edge (v1,v2) has the maximum weight?

Tags: r, igraph

Given a vertex v1, how can I get the vertex v2 whose edge (v1,v2) has the maximum weight?

My approach to the problem is this one:

```
library(igraph)
maxEdge = max(E(g)[from(id)]$weight
which(E(g)$weight==maxEdge))
```

But I don't know how to get the vertex ID. Any ideas?

Minimal example data

```
library(igraph)

g1 <- graph.full(5)
V(g1)$name <- 1:5    
g2 <- graph.full(5)
V(g2)$name <- 6:10
g3 <- graph.ring(5)
V(g3)$name <- 11:15
g <- g1 + g2 + g3 + edge('1', '6') + edge('1', '11')
V(g)$name <- letters[1:vcount(g)]
# Random data
set.seed(ecount(g))
E(g)$weight <- runif(ecount(g))

maxEdge = max(E(g)[from(1)]$weight)
idEdge = which(E(g)$weight==maxEdge)
```

My approach get the edge id (idEdge). However, want get the vertex ID!

For instance:

```
V(g)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"

E(g)[from("a")] -> $weight
[1]  b -- a -> 0.97175023
[2]  c -- a -> 0.08375751
[3]  d -- a -> 0.87386992
[4]  e -- a -> 0.32923136
[26] f -- a -> 0.10740653
[27] k -- a -> 0.56277556
```

Considering the example above, what I need is a function that must return  "b" or "2".

Comment: Can you provide some *minimal* example data that is reproducible? - [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should `set.seed` to make your example reproducible. Better to get the expected result.

Comment: I edited the original post to make my example reproducible (using set.seed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the ID of the edge that has the maximal weight, you can use `get.edge(graph, edge.id)` to get the vertex IDs of the endpoints. So, the full solution is something like:

```
edge.seq <- E(g)[from(source)]
max.weight <- max(edge.seq$weight)
get.edges(graph, edge.seq[edge.seq$weight == max.weight])
```

I'm not an expert in R so maybe there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get.adjedgelist` to get adjacent edges for all the graph. Then looping through the resulted list to take the edge with maximum weight.

```
lapply(get.adjedgelist(g),
       function(x)
         E(g)[x[which.max(get.edge.attribute(g,'weight',x))]])
```

Checking this in a small example:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)
g <- graph.full(4)
V(g)$name <- 1:5    
V(g)$name <- letters[1:vcount(g)]
E(g)$weight <- runif(ecount(g))
E(g)$label=round(E(g)$weight,2)
ll <- lapply(get.adjedgelist(g),
       function(x)
         E(g)[x[which.max(get.edge.attribute(g,'weight',x))]])
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

[image]

```
$a
Edge sequence:
    e       
e [2] c -- a

$b
Edge sequence:
    e       
e [5] d -- b

$c
Edge sequence:
    e       
e [4] c -- b

$d
Edge sequence:
    e       
e [5] d -- b
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I still can not see how to get the id of the adjacent vertex.

Comment: What is the **id** of the adjacent vertex? Can you please append your question with the expected result!

Comment: I edited the original post giving an example showing the expected result.